# Failed login for user

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2013

I'm developing a website for sharepoint using asp.net, it is connected to a database. In visual studio server explorer, the database is accessible using a new sql user I created. I granted sysadmin permissions to that user. However, when I deploy the site and run it, it gives me this error 'login failed for user'. 
The sql server is configured to allow mixed authentications. I restarted the server, I played with the user permissions but nothing ever changed.
The connection string I got it from server explorer which I'm sure it is correct:
`Data Source=servertest;Initial Catalog=qDB;User ID=me2;Password=***********"`

What should I do? I've tried every possible solution I found on google and I ended up here.

Comment: Try like this by editing your connection string , Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Comment: This solved it but may I ask how and why?

Comment: How did you solve it??

Comment: I changed my connection string to be the same as your connection string but I don't understand how this change worked.

Comment: I think your connection string not for mixed mode authentication, your sql server configured as mixed mode.

Comment: If it is working my answer, please accept my answer that would help others too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this by editing your connection string:-

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had same scenario this worked for me

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=XYZ\SHAREPOINT;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use connection string like this

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="KhadamatConnectionString" 
    value="Server=[copy name from Your ServerName of SSMS];Database=AcaService;uid=admin;pwd=mypass;" />
</appSettings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="KhadamatConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=[copy name from Your ServerName of SSMS];Initial Catalog=AcaService;User ID=admin;Password=mypass;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```